# windows 8 disable smartcard plug and play

Tags: windows, windows-8, smartcard

I have a delay problem reading my smartcard and I think that is possible to be a problem with Smartcard Plug and Play service.

I googled about this and found that is possible to disable with gpedit.msc ..the problem is that gpedit.msc is not accesible with Windows 8 (non professional).

In windows 7 there is a registry called EnableScPnP that works, but I didn't found this at Win 8.

How can I disable Smartcard Plug and Play with win8?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the same EnableScPnp registry key (see below) and rebooting. According to the docs, it's not supposed to require a reboot, but I've verified a reboot is required for this setting. From what I've read, EnableScPnp should work on W7 or W8 or W8.1. According to SmartCard.admx, it certainly hasn't changed registry keys.

Oddly if I set the registry key on W7/W8/W8.1, it doesn't say it is set in gpedit.msc. There isn't supposed to be a W7/W8 policy cache, is there? Not quite sure how that works. I thought manually registry edits showed up in gpedit.msc, in the old days circa XP?

Possibly I forgot to reboot, but a potential issue I saw on W8.1 is that there is a new feature called Group Policy Caching which interferes with writing directly to any group policy registry key. There is some kind of cache in e.g. "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol". I don't know how to update the policy cache without using gpedit.msc. You can disable policy caching though (although again you would need gpedit.msc). But I'm pretty sure if you rebooted, any value in the policy cache would overwrite any registry key (if I run gpupdate /force this is certainly true).

I searched a bit, but I haven't found any information from Microsoft or elsewhere on how people are supposed to modify the policy cache now. Given how new 8.1 is, I expect many tech people will start to complain about this very soon, since many tip blogs give registry keys to modify, which may no longer work (if you have a policy cache), and you'll have to use gpedit.msc or some other unknown mechanism to modify all these settings going forward.

If you are on W7, you are in "luck"... I've found that eventually the PnP logic just craters and stops working forever, even after a reboot. I love Windows.

For reference, this is the value that's supposed to work in W7/8/8.1:

gpedit.msc -> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Smart Card : "Turn on Smart Card Plug and Play service" = "Disabled"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ScPnP]
"EnableScPnP"=dword:00000000

** Be sure to reboot after setting the policy or registry key.