# How to disable Winscard Discovery in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, smartcard

I'm testing smart cards using ACR122U. However, when I put a card on it, Windows will automatically send APDU commands to it.

According to the question [windows 8 disable smartcard plug and play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356769/windows-8-disable-smartcard-plug-and-play), I disabled Smart Card Plug And Play. But I can still see the PIV selection which is called [Winscard Discovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn468754(v=vs.85).aspx).

How can I disable this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 solutions

### 1) Edit computer policies

- Launch gpedit.msc
- Section Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Smart Card

Disable Smartcard driver popup:

- Smart Card Plug and Play service: disable

Disable smartcard timeout on ISOB' card removing

- Turn on certificate propagation from smartcard: disable

### 2) Disable smartcard filter (only to disable popup message)

To disable or enable the smartcard filter, use "DisableSCFilterWindows7.reg" and "EnableSCFilterWindows7.reg"

### 3) Install a dummy card provider

The dummy card provider will let the system to know the smartcards.Thus, it will not try to identify the card, sending commands, 
and will not popup error message.

Sources: Notes from an ASK driver and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976832