# JCIDE and pyapdutool

Tags: javacard

I wrote a code with gcide. when I want to debug it in gpshell I saw this message :

```
Start jcvm_gp successfully.
Connect Simulator:eJava Token successfully.
>> /card -a ""
ATR=3B 70 13 00 00

>> 00 A4 04 00 00
<< .. 90 00

>> set-key 255/1/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F 255/2/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F 255/3/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F

>> init-update 255
<< ..90 00

>> ext-auth
<< ..90 00

>> upload 
<< .. 90 00

>> install A000000308 A00000030800001000 A00000030800001000  
<< .. 90 00

>> cardinfo
<< .. 90 00

Card Manager AID   :  A000000003000000
Card Manager state :  OP_READY

    Application:  SELECTABLE (--------) A00000030800001000
    Load File  :      LOADED (--------) A000000308
     Module    :                        A00000030800001000

 1. Disconnect apdu port with JCVM successfully. 

 2. Connect JAVACOS Virtual Contact Reader 0 successfully. Connect JAVACOS        Virtual Contactless Reader 1  successfully.

 3. Connect CL port failed,IP:127.0.0.1:Port:0.
    Reason: The requested address is not valid in its context.
 4. Connect CB port successful,IP:127.0.0.1  Port:51836 T0
```

but for example when I wrote command `/select` ,I get Jcvm is not connected.

```
>> /select "A0 00 00 03 08 00 00 10 00"
>> 00 A4 04 00 09 A0 00 00 03 08 00 00 10 00 00
<< 00 00   Jcvm is not connected
Win32 Interface already disconnected.
```

also I enable pcsc interface and I use simulator:ejavatoken but some time in debug mode it is connected *PyAPDUTool* but some times no.
can every body help me?

Comment: Thanks Abraham for editing

Comment: answer is in post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040169/how-to-disable-winscard-discovery-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Remember that [eJava Token](http://www.javacardos.com/store/smartcard_eJavaToken.php) only have contact port, you can not Connect CL port.

If you want to connect contactless port,  change JCIDE simulator to "Simulator: Default", "Simulator: A40CR" or "Simulator: A22CR", then you can connect either contact or contactless at will in [pyapdutool](http://www.javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=641)/gpshell.