# pyapdutool is not called in JCIDE

Tags: javacard

When I want to debug my code in JCIDE via pyapdutool I get message 
"Connect CL port  failed .Please disconnect JAVACOS Virtual Contact 
Reader 0  first"  and green message not show there for 
I can't run   pyapdutool.
 can every body help me?
    [image]

`
[image]

and stop in this step
[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you please tell me the concrete operation step? We will reproduce your problem according to your steps.Then we can help you solve it.

Comment: I attached my image step. It was called fot two/three times but I don't know what happend and after that pyapdutool not called no tilmes.

Comment: In pyapdutool,  please connect JAVACOS Virtual Contact Reader 0. Because you have selected " Simulator: eJava Token" in JCIDE  and  eJava Token only have contact port, you can not select  JAVACOS Virtual Contactless Reader 1 .

Comment: Another solution: Change JCIDE simulator to "Simulator: Default"  or "Simulator: A40CR",  then you can connect either contact or contactless at will in pyapdutool.

Comment: in pyapdutool I selected reader 0 but I have a error now. and I tested Simulator.Default It has problem too. for first time I have a problem with smulator :default bt ejavatoken is connected. but now both of them has problem.I restart JCIED but It is not connected

Comment: Do you use Teamviewer?  If yes, could  you please send your ID and pw to javacardos@gmail.com? Our technical support  can do remote assistance for you.

Comment: I did evry thing you saidbut I has problem. I attached result image

Comment: the answer is in post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040169/how-to-disable-winscard-discovery-in-windows-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: 
To slove this problem,  please refer to this post  [How to disable Winscard Discovery in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040169/how-to-disable-winscard-discovery-in-windows-10)

From the screenshot you provided, do you know who send the commands indicated by red rectangular frame?  It seems that something has automatically connected the virtual reader and send APDU commands to it.

[image]

Comment: No  I don't know. I think these are for jcide. what happen? what can I do?

Comment: Please refer to this topic  to solve your problem.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040169/how-to-disable-winscard-discovery-in-windows-10